# Hard links - storage

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm trying to understand hard links but struggle understanding the following:

I created a file "original" and then created a hard link to "original". When "original" is modified the modification is availible in the hard link so it isn't a copy. When however the file is deleted the hard link still contans the content of that file but where is that data stored?

Comment: The two links point to the same physical code blocks on the disc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of a filename as a label for something. With hardlinks you have two labels for the same thing. If you remove one label (delete a file), you still have the second label pointing to the data. Only when the last label is removed, the data will be deleted as well.